# How to group result by region with pig latin?

Tags: hadoop, dataset, bigdata, apache-pig

I'm new to Hadoop PIG and I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
region_id        region         participation   score

    1             SSA               YES          10
    1             SSA               NO           22
    2             MONTPELIER        YES          15
    ....
```

I want to calculate the sum of scores for each region. The final display that I'm looking for is : 
REGION - SCORE, for example:

```
SSA - 32
```

I loaded my data:

```
data = load '/user/cloudera/datapi/pigdata.csv' using PigStorage (',') AS
 (id:int, region:chararray, participation:chararray, score:int);
```

Then grouped the data by region:

```
split_region = GROUP data by region;
```

Finally:

```
RES= foreach split_region GENERATE SUM(data.score), data.region;
```

the **RES** variable contains the sum of score for each region but it display all the occurrences of the region like so:

```
(32 , {SSA,SSA})
```

What is the missing command/instruction to display `(32, SSA)` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `group` instead of `data.region`

```
RES = foreach split_region GENERATE SUM(data.score), group;
```

See [here](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#GROUP) for source. When you use the GROUP operator,
*The first field is named "group" (do not confuse this with the GROUP operator) and is the same type as the group key.*

Comment: Thank you so much! can you please explain the use of group?

Answer (score 0):

Group operator is used to bring all the records with similar key into the same bag. This helps us to perform aggregations on the the columns.